# Нереальный индекс -1

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

В список с клавиатуры пишу стринги, на экран нужно вывести индекс первой стринги которая меньше предыдущей, пример:

золото
  курага
  лом
  дерево

Моя цель индекс слова "лом" , на экране жду цифру 2, мой код выводит -1
Код:

```
int indexFirstErrorNumber = 0; // сохранит индекс нужного элемента
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(10);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arrayList.add(reader.readLine());
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) { // итераций 8-ть т.к. в каждом цикле я "заглядываю" на шаг вперёд
        if (arrayList.get(y).length() <= arrayList.get(y + 1).length()) continue; //если "первый"  меньше или равен "второму", 
                                                                                                       //то не реагирую   
        else indexFirstErrorNumber = arrayList.indexOf(y + 1);  // в противном случае запоминаю индекс
        System.out.println(indexFirstErrorNumber);                 //индекс на экран 
        System.out.println(arrayList.get(y + 1));                   //  слово на экран
        break;
    }
```

Что я пропустил? почему -1? Таких индексов не существует

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else indexFirstErrorNumber = y + 1; // в противном случае запоминаю индекс
```

А Вы что запоминаете?

Comment: Неужели всё так просто!? Работает. Вы знаете почему выводит -1?

Comment: @CoffeJava Знаю. Потому что Вы пытаетесь в списке найти `2`, а их там нет.

Comment: @CoffeJava https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: думал так: в переменную запишу индекс стринги расположеную по адресу имя_списка.её_индекс + 1

Comment: @CoffeJava Прочитайте, что делает `indexOf`, ссылка - в предыдущем комментарии.

Comment: док ещё не читал но как-так "нет"? даже если я ошибся в вычислении индекса, то думал, в крайнем случае получу индекс следующего слова - "дерево"

Comment: хорошо, не буду препираться, ссылку Вы мне дали, Ваш код рабочий, спасибо!